# Extracting zipped file from ResourceStream throws error "Invalid stored block lengths"

Tags: java, maven, zip, embedded-resource

I am trying to extract a ZIP file from my current JAR using:

```
InputStream resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
```

This get the correct `InputStream`, but it gives an error when I try to unzip it using the following code (I'm storing each file into a `Hashmap<file, filename>`):

```
public static HashMap<String, String> readZip(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<>();
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
    ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while (IOUtils.read(zipInputStream, buffer) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
            }
            list.put(stringBuilder.toString(), entry.getName());
        }
        zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipInputStream.closeEntry();
    zipInputStream.close();
    return list;
}
```

However when I try to do this, I get this exception (on `IOUtils.read`)

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
   at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing this wrong? I've done plenty of googling of the error, and I didn't see anything related to my issue.

Comment: So your JAR contains an entry which is zipped? You want to read the bytes of this entry and read it through a `ZipInputStream`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's about it

Comment: This suggests the file is corrupt. Try decompressing it with a normal unzip utility.

Comment: Works fine, unless I take the file out of the jar after I've compiled it. So I'm guessing maven/java is doing something to it during compiling?

Comment: Regardless of that, you're making a severe mistake concatenating the data into a StringBuilder and saving it as a String. First, you aren't even doing that correctly, as you're ignoring the read count when constructing each String. Secondly, *String is not a container for binary data.* You should copy each entry to a ByteArrayOutputStream and return a HashMap<String, byte[]>.

Comment: Alright, will do (wrote this pretty late at night, as usual). Anything you can infer about the main issue though?

Comment: Main issue is that the resource is corrupt, or isn't a ZIP file at all. How exactly are you building it?

Comment: mvn clean install? Or the ZIP, it's created with Windows.

Comment: From what it appears, when it's compiled the zip gets corrupted in the jar.

Comment: Just a minute. There's a large unexplained distance between running maven and building an.zip file and adding it into an JAR, and none of it involves compilation.

Comment: When maven compiles, it uses the Maven Resource Plugin to add the files into the final jar. It appears that by default it uses UTF-8, which was destroying the zip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @PaulBGD's answer above. It saved me hours to figure out what happened to my system I add the following new snippets into my `pom.xml` file (which I didn't realize is the root cause before reading Paul's answer):

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.version</include>
      <include>**/*.properties</include>
      <include>**/*.xml</include>
      <include>**/*.csv</include>
      <include>**/*.txt</include>
      <include>**/*.gif</include>
      <include>**/*.json</include>
      <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
      <include>rythm/**</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

However I didn't take Paul's answer directly, instead I don't think those `xlsx` files should go through the resource plugin's filtering pipeline, thus I added another `resource` into pom:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.xlsx</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

And it fixed my problem without changing the source encoding setting from `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: This seems like the better answer, marked it as such :)

Answer (score 7):

After a few more hours of searching, I decompiled the maven-resources-plugin and noticed it used UTF-8 encoding by default. I quickly looked up the encoding I would need (ISO-8859-1) and put it in my pom.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Now the zip file copies into the jar perfectly, no corruption at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, save me hours to understand what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Change spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.0.4.RELEASE. It worked for me.

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
```