# MATLAB java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths while reading zraw

Tags: java, matlab

The question might be long but I want to give as much info as possible! Sorry.

I'm working with MATLAB, and I have a .zraw file, where my pixels are.
The .zraw file has **320.449** bytes

I managed to read this file in MATLAB and get the data.

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.zraw','Select the image file');
dir = strcat(PathName,FileName);

FID = fopen(dir);
elementType = 'uint8';
compressedData = fread(FID, inf, 'uint8=>uint8' );

buffer = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
zlib = java.util.zip.InflaterOutputStream( buffer );
zlib.write( compressedData, 0, numel( compressedData ) );
zlib.close();
data = typecast( buffer.toByteArray(), elementType )';
```

When executing this code in MATLAB:

```
compressedData has 320449x1 uint8 
data has 1515360x1 uint8
buffer is 1x1 ByteArrayOutputStream
zlib is 1x1 InflaterOutputStream
data has all the expected values and I can work with it.
```

Everything works fine!

**But now**, I wanted to change a few things. Reading the [MATLAB documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html), fread() has more calls.

I want to skip 2 bytes each byte. As the file is being read with 'uint8', I could do that by writing:

```
compressedData = fread(FID, inf, 'uint8=>uint8', 2);
```

After this call, compressedData has 106.817 Bytes. As expected, due to I want to read a third of the file (320.449)

Now is time to create the buffer and Inflate it. However, if I write the same lines than before:

```
buffer = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
zlib = java.util.zip.InflaterOutputStream( buffer );
zlib.write( compressedData, 0, numel( compressedData ) );
```

Then I get this exception:

> > Java exception occurred: java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
> >     at java.util.zip.InflaterOutputStream.write(InflaterOutputStream.java:273)

I searched a little bit in the [Inflater documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html#Inflater(boolean)). It seems that I have to use the nowarp boolean to avoid the checksum from zlib.

So now, I repeat everything but now:

```
buffer = java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
zlib = java.util.zip.InflaterOutputStream( buffer ,java.util.zip.Inflater(true));
zlib.write( compressedData, 0, numel( compressedData ) );
```

With those lines, I get the exception where I'm stuck at:

> > Java exception occurred: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
> >     at java.util.zip.InflaterOutputStream.write(InflaterOutputStream.java:273)

I found a few related issues [here](https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/zipexception-invalid-stored-block-lengths/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235229/extracting-zipped-file-from-resourcestream-throws-error-invalid-stored-block-le/25243500), but I'm not sure what should be my next step to fix this...