# Uploading excel file using Jersey and Apache POI - Getting ZIP Exception - Invalid stored block lengths

Tags: jersey, apache-poi, aws-api-gateway, tomcat8, xlsx

I have a REST endpoint written using Jersey that looks like this where I'm trying to upload an excel file and read its contents using Apache POI

```
@Path("/batch")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response batchUploadAssets(@HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) final String authorizationHeader,
            @HeaderParam(CustomVamsHeaders.ORGANISATION) final Integer vamsOrg,
            final FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart,
            @Context final ContainerRequestContext request) {

   BodyPart bodyPart = formDataMultiPart.getBodyParts().get(0);

   final BodyPartEntity entity = (BodyPartEntity) bodyPart.getEntity();

   InputStream inputStream = entity.getInputStream();

   XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); -> This line throws the exception below

}
```

Exception StackTrace

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.readFromInflater(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:586)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.readDeflated(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:551)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.read(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:458)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.read(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:78)
.......
.......
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:307)
```

It works fine when I run my app on my local tomcat instance. However, when I deploy my app to an EC2 instance and access it via AWS API Gateway, that's when I get this error. Any idea what I need to do differently?

Comment: Check if the bytes uploaded via EC2 and local tomcat are different. My guess is that API Gateway makes some changes

Comment: Hi. I had the same error, but did not work with tomcat. This post helped, maybe you can use it in some way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012630/6572357

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had exactly the same issue. The problem was the instantiation of the `FormDataBodyPart` using `IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` as value. Instead, do something like that:

```
FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
FormDataContentDisposition contentDisposition = FormDataContentDisposition.name("file").fileName("upload-sample.xlsx").build();

FormDataBodyPart bodyPart = new FormDataBodyPart();
bodyPart.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);
bodyPart.setValue(MediaType.valueOf("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"), inputStream);
form.bodyPart(bodyPart);
```