# Why does "Inflator" algorithm fails for UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: scala, encoding, utf-8, compression, iso-8859-1

I wrote the following code in order to decompress messages that were zipped using the Deflator algorithm:

```
  def decompressMsg[V: StringDecoder](msg: String): Try[V] = {
    if (msg.startsWith(CompressionHeader)) {
      logger.debug(s"Message before decompression is: ${msg}")
      val compressedByteArray =
        msg.drop(CompressionHeader.length).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
      val inflaterInputStream = new InflaterInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedByteArray)
      )
      val decompressedByteArray = readDataFromInflaterInputStream(inflaterInputStream)

      StringDecoder.decode[V](new String(decompressedByteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).tap {
        decompressedMsg => logger.info(s"Message after decompression is: ${decompressedMsg}")
      })
    } else {
      StringDecoder.decode[V](msg)
    }
  }

private def readDataFromInflaterInputStream(
      inflaterInputStream: InflaterInputStream
  ): Array[Byte] = {
    val outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    var runLoop = true
    while (runLoop) {
      val buffer = new Array[Byte](BufferSize)
      val len = inflaterInputStream.read(buffer) // ERROR IS THROWN FROM THIS LINE!!
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len)
      if (len < BufferSize) runLoop = false
    }
    outputStream.toByteArray
  }
```

The input argument 'msg' was compressed using the Deflator. The above code fails with the error message:

> invalid stored block lengths java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid
> stored block lengths

After I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235229/extracting-zipped-file-from-resourcestream-throws-error-invalid-stored-block-le), I changed StandardCharsets.UTF_8 to StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 and surprisingly, the code passed and returned the desired behaviour.

I don't want to work with an encoding different than UTF_8. Do you have an idea how to make my code work with UTF_8 encoding?

Comment: You already have the answer to your problem. The compressed data _has no encoding_. It is simply a sequence of bytes. You should not be passing it as a string in the first place. It's not a string. Treating as ISO 8859 simply leaves it as the original bytes without corruption, which is why that works.

Comment: The *uncompressed* data might be encoded in UTF-8, but compressed data is "just a bunch of bytes".   Typically, if you have text, you encode it to bytes, then compress; so decompress, then decode.